# Como implementar uma textarea de forma responsiva?

Tags: javascript, html5, css3, layout-responsivo

Quero usar uma `<textarea>`, mas em vez de usar `rows="4" cols="100"`, queria usar algo deste gênero: `style="width: 80%"` para que o layout fique responsivo. Mas uma vez que isto não funciona, ou seja, usa-se o tamanho a 80% mas não fica responsive, como posso solucionar o problema? Nota: estou a usar uma framework que vinha no template.

Segue o exemplo:
http://jsfiddle.net/ndQKL/1/

Atenção, o jsfiddle.net faz com que a `textarea` fique responsive. Se aplicar numa página em branco não fica.

Comment: Poste seu código, se for possível no jsfiddle.net

Comment: Olha, isso funciona sim. Deve ter algum outro erro que está cometendo. Editado: vi aqui. Ele está funcionando. A única coisa que falta é usar media queries para definir os pontos de quebra, caso realmente queira pontos diferentes. **O que você entende como responsive**?

Comment: já editei o post

Comment: fica responsive devido ao jsfiddle.net, mas se tentar aplicar numa janela em branco não fica

Comment: Ah, seu problema é que deve estar usando um framework de CSS, como Twitter boostrap, mas não está sobrescrevendo corretamente o CSS. É simples a resposta. Confirme se está usando um framework.

Comment: sim, estou a usar uma framework

Comment: Altere a pergunta e coloque o framework que está usando. Se possível, link seu jsfiddle com um CSS padrão do framework que está usando. Desse modo vamos ver exatamente o problema que está passado. Sua solução provavelmente é só melhorar a especificidade do seletor de CSS

Comment: responsive é o tamanha da textarea editar consoante o tamanho da janela.

Comment: Responsive tipicamente refere-se a layouts que "funcionam" em vários tamanhos de ecrãs (por oposição a precisar de scrolling horizontal, ficar com margens enormes ou ter páginas diferentes para telemóveis).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Eu faço assim (Usando o Bootstrap):

```css
textarea {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;

  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="span9">
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Este erro ocorre porque, ao usar um framwork de CSS, como Twitter boostrap, tal framework especifica a largura e altura de elementos como text e textarea.

Neste caso, depois de aplicar sua alteração com CSS, você deveria usar um inspetor, como Firebug ou DevTools para ver se o seletor CSS tem especificidade suficiente.

O código postado até então não dá ideia exata de aonde o problema está, mas ajustando a especificidade do seletor e sobrescrevendo o padrão de sua biblioteca de CSS isso irá resolver seu problema.

Dois modos mais simples de aumentar a especificidade é, para classe que que seu textarea possui ou a própria tag textarea, adicionar após o `width: 80%` um `!important` ou prefixar o seletor com um um elemento com ID.

```
textarea {
  width: 80% !important; /* Idealmente !important deve ser evitado */
}
```

No caso da outra solução

```
#algumid textarea {
   width: 80%;
}
```

### Especificidade de CSS

Uma ajuda rapida sobre isso pode ser vista em http://www.maujor.com/tutorial/especificidade.php

CÁLCULOS:

> 1°.-) Conte o número (quantidade) 
>   de atributos id no seletor;
>
> 2°.-) Conte o número (quantidade)
>    de atributos classe no seletor;
>
> 3°.-) Conte o número (quantidade) 
>   de tag's HTML no seletor;
>
> 4°.-) Escreva os números obtidos, 
>   da esquerda para a direitae na mesma
>   ordem em que foram levantados (id,classe,tag).
>
> Havendo empate na pontuação vale o efeito cascata a última regra declarada prevalece.

Tem outros detalhes além disso sobre especificidade de seletor para critérios de desempate

Comment: Quem deu -1 pode explicar o motivo?

Answer (score 0):

Aconselho você fazer estilização sempre no arquivo de estilos (`.css`, `.scss`, etc) e não inline ou incorporado.

Tente assim:

1. Remova o style que esta inline do textarea;
2. Use esse css:

```css
#desc_pt{
    width: 80% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A aplicação do estilo ao tag textarea está correcta. É por isso que funciona no Fiddler. Se não funciona na sua página, isso significa que há outros estilos que se estão a sobrepor a esse.

Para saber o que se passa, o mais simples é abrir a sua página no Chrome. Instale os [Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) se for preciso. Depois faça click-direito sobre a sua textarea, e escolha Inspect Element, e os Developer Tools abrem-se. Do lado direito tem o painel Styles, e aí pode ver que estilos estão ao ser aplicados a este tag, e porque é que o seu tag não funciona como quer.